# Difference between cxx_binary() and cxx_library()

Tags: buck

What is the difference between the two?  On the documentation, they seem to have the same arguments?  Do they do the same thing? I haven't been able to find much info about Buck besides the official documentation.

Comment: from the name I would guess the first one builds an executable and the second a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `cxx_library` is a C or C++ (or Objective C) library that might be compiled static or shared.

A `cxx_binary` is a C or C++ (or Objective C) executable. You can run the result of a `cxx_binary`, both outside of Buck and inside a `genrule`.

A `cxx_binary` must contain a translation-unit (`srcs`) that provides a `main` function, since this will be the entry-point for the executable.

In terms of arguments, the big difference is that a `cxx_library` has `exported_headers`. These are headers that any library that depends on it are provided access to.

You might find this interesting: https://github.com/njlr/buckaroo-protobuf-example